# XamlParseException occured - animating an ellipse

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have the following code to animate the width of the ellipse forever until the window is closed. However, it throws `XamlParseExceptionError`. Could someone point out to me where I made the mistake?

`

```
        </TextBlock>

        <TextBlock x:Uid="ProductName" Localization.Attributes="$Content(Readable Unmodifiable)">
            <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock x:Uid="ProductNameTip" Localization.Attributes="$Content(ToolTip Readable Modifiable)">
                    A photo editor that will make everyone look beautiful
                </TextBlock>
            </TextBlock.ToolTip>
            Amazing Photo Editor
        </TextBlock>

        <Ellipse Name="Circle" 
                 Width="100" 
                 Height="100" 
                 Fill="Red">
            <Ellipse.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Ellipse.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="Circle" 
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" 
                                             From="1" 
                                             To="100" 
                                             Duration="0:0:5" 
                                             AutoReverse="True" 
                                             RepeatBehavior="Forever">

                            </DoubleAnimation>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Ellipse.Triggers>
        </Ellipse>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

`

Comment: In XamlParseException in InnerException property you can read string that can describe your error (Message property). And you can write it here.

Comment: @acrilige Thanks. It says `{"'Circle' is not a valid value for property 'Target'."}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Storyboard.TargetName Attached Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetname.aspx) instead of `Storyboard.Target`.

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Circle"
```

Comment: BTW: In your case it is needless. Remove the TargetName and it will work too.

Comment: Ah! I didn't see that coming. Yes, I had wanted `TargetName`, not `Target` Thanks for pointing this one out. Perhaps I should considering turning off my Intellisense and use more of my Intelligence.